# Странное название загружаемого файла через PHP

Tags: php, mysql, fileupload

Загружаю файл на сервер с помощью этого кода:

```
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "docs/incoming/" . 
$newfilename);          
$location="docs/incoming/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
```

Но после загрузки файла на сервер, в базе прописывается довольно странное название типа:

```
????JFIF??C%# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(??C
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((???"?????}!1AQa"q2???#B??R??$3br?    
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUV
```

В чем может быть проблема и как исправить?

Comment: Какая переменная записывается в БД? И что с самим файлом - он с каким именем записывается на диск (если вообще записывается)?

Comment: Покажите что вы пишите в базу, больше похоже на содержимое самого файла

Comment: В БД записывается $location. А название файла 0101.jpg например. Посмотрел на диске файл загружается с названием 0101.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть с кодировкой.

Для начала нужно идти непосредствено к запросу в базу данных. Так как на примере не видно никакого запроса в базу и пока он буден выполнен переменная $location еще можен поменять свое значение.

Нужно дойти до самого запроса INSERT. Тогда будет ясно на стороне PHP или MySQL проблема. И решать тогда будет значительно проще

Для поиска причин подобных проблем на стороне PHP удобно использовать  [Xdebug](https://habrahabr.ru/post/328094/)